# How do I find the number of characters in a string using scheme programming language?

Tags: string, list, recursion, scheme, string-length

I used `string-length` to get the number of characters but I am having difficulties in defining a recursive function. Should I convert the string to a list and then count the elements?

Answer (score 2):

There's no useful way of doing this recursively (or even tail recursively): strings in Scheme are objects which know how long they are.  There *would* be such an approach in a language like C where strings don't know how long they are but are delimited by some special marker.  So for instance if `(special-marker? s i)` told you whether the `i`'th element of `s` was the special marker object, then you could write a function to know how long the string was:

```
(define (silly-string-length s)
  (let silly-string-length-loop ([i 1])
    (if (special-marker? s i)
        (- i 1)
        (silly-string-length-loop (+ i 1)))))
```

But now think about how you would implement `special-marker?` in Scheme: in particular here's the obvious implementation:

```
(define (special-marker? s i)
  (= i (+ (string-length s) 1)))
```

And you can see that `silly-string-length` is now just a terrible version of `string-length`.

Well, if you wanted to make it look even more terrible, you could, as you suggest, convert a string to a list and then compute the length of the lists.  Lists *are* delimited by a special marker object, `()` so this approach is reasonable:

```
(define (length-of-list l)
  (let length-of-list-loop ([i 0]
                            [lt l])
    (if (null? lt)
        i
        (length-of-list-loop (+ i 1) (rest lt)))))
```

So you could write

```
(define (superficially-less-silly-string-length s)
  (length-of-list
   (turn-string-into-list s)))
```

But, wait, how do you write `turn-string-into-list`?  Well, something like this perhaps:

```
(define (turn-string-into-list s)
  (let ([l (string-length s)])
    (let loop ([i 0]
               [r '()])
      (if (= i l)
          (reverse r)
          (loop (+ i 1)
                (cons (string-ref s i) r))))))
```

And this ... uses `string-length`.

Comment: writing terrible versions of functions is the best way to learn. :)

Comment: (when one have analyzed and realized  _why_ they're terrible)

Comment: @WillNess: I agree.  Also just reinventing wheels is useful – or example discovering you've just rediscovered some long-known technique but because you discovered it yourself you now really understand it.

Answer (score 1):

What is the problem with?

```
(string-length string)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the question is a puzzle "count characters in a string without using string-length",
then maybe:

```
(define (my-string-length s)
  (define (my-string-length t n)
    (if (string=? s t)  n
        (my-string-length
          (string-append t (string (string-ref s n))) (+ n 1))))
  (my-string-length "" 0))
```

or:

```
(define (my-string-length s)
  (define (my-string-length n)
    (define (try thunk)
      (call/cc (lambda (k)
          (with-exception-handler (lambda (x)
              (k n))
            thunk))))
    (try (lambda ()
            (string-ref s n)
            (my-string-length (+ n 1)))))
  (my-string-length 0))
```

(but of course string-ref will be using the base string-length or equivalent)